# Querying dates in Realm React Native

Tags: realm, react-native, react-native-ios

[EDITED]

I'd like to query and filter by dates in realm. Here's my code:

```
    let factories = realm.objects('Factory')
    for(factory of factories) {
       let toys = realm.objects('Toy').filtered('factory_id == factory.id')
       let lowerBound = new Date(year + '-1-1T00:00:00Z')
       let uppperBound = new Date(year + '-2-1T00:00:00Z')
       let janToys = toys.filtered('created_at > lowerBound AND created_at < uppperBound')
    }
```

`year` is a variable declared before the code snippet above.

This doesn't work and I'm pretty sure it's because the date format is not correct.

Here is the date format when I log toys:

`Fri Mar 24 2017 16:01:59 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

I'd like to know how to query realm dates. I can't find it in the documentation and other posts here. I'd appreciate any help. If this is not a date format issue, please tell me.

Thank you!

EDIT: I added the outside loop. This may not be a date format issue. Here is the error message:

```
    Error: Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value`
```

Comment: What happens if you create your lowerBound and upperBound like this: `let lowerBound = new Date(year + '-01-01T00:00:00');` and `let uppperBound = new Date(year + '-02-01T00:00:00');`

Comment: @JanPeter, hi, that was an honest mistake. I tried running it and this error shows up:

`Error: Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value`

Comment: Well, this is pretty cryptic to me, as I'm using realm not that often :/ But I would store the date as an integer and transform the date to a unix timestamp before saving and reading it. Makes things a lot easier for me, since handling date types is not easy when switching between languages often^^

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try to use it as a last resort. If I can't solve it the Realm way, I can use your idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Realm does not support dot operators inside its queries. Forcing Realm to be relational is not allowed. As a solution, I transformed my usage to follow NoSQL convention. Passing in objects instead of declaring relationships.